# How to get fields of classtype in scala?

Tags: scala, reflection

I'm trying to write a function, which returns a map with fields and types of a class.

The function call is like

```
val map: Map[String, Any] = getFields(classOf[User])
```

and the function looks like:

```
def getFields[A](cls: Class[A]): Map[String, Any] = {
    var map: Map[String, Any] = Map()
    for (field <- classOf[cls].getDeclaredFields()) {
        field.getName match {
            case "id" => {}
            case _ => map += (field.getName() -> field.getType)
        }
    }
    println(map)
    map
}
```

, but I'm getting an error at `classOf[cls]` *(not found: type cls)*. How can I get the fields of a class like this? Also, as return type, is there a better solution than `Map[String, Any]`, when I want to match the fieldtype afterwards?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cls` is already a `Class`, no need to call `classOf` on it.

Btw, your code can be written much shorter:

```
cls.getDeclaredFields.filter(_.getName != "id").map(f => f.getName -> f.getType).toMap[String, Any]
```

And no, it is not possible to get a more general type than `Any` because your fields may have completely different types.

Answer (score 0):

Using reflection & ClassTag & @sschaef shorter version :

```
import scala.reflect._

def getFieldsOf[A: ClassTag ](): Map[String, Any] = {
    val cls = classTag[A].runtimeClass
    cls.getDeclaredFields.filter(_.getName != "id")
                         .map(f => f.getName -> f.getType)
                         .toMap[String, Any]
}
```

Calling above function without any parameter(s) - only the class name - makes it intuitive.

```
var map: Map[String, Any] = getFieldsOf[User]
println (map)
```